# Terraform Azure AKS - How to install azure-keyvault-secrets-provider add-on

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I have an `AKS` kubernetes cluster provisioned with `terraform`. And I need to enable the `azure-keyvault-secrets-provider` add-on.

Using the azure CLI, I could enable it as follows:

```
az aks enable-addons --addons azure-keyvault-secrets-provider --name myAKSCluster --resource-group myResourceGroup
```

But, how can I do it with the `terraform`? I tried the documentation, but doesn't mention anything about a secret driver except only one block as follows:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s_cluster" {
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      default_node_pool
    ]
    prevent_destroy = false
  }

  key_vault_secrets_provider {
    secret_rotation_enabled = true
  }
...
}
```

Is the above `key_vault_secrets_provider` doing the same thing as the azure CLI command `az aks enable-addons --addons azure-keyvault-secrets-provider --name myAKSCluster --resource-group myResourceGroup` ?

Because according to the terraform documentation, this `key_vault_secrets_provider` block is only for rotating the keyvault secrets. But no mention about enabling the driver.

My requirement is to:

1. Enable the secret provider driver
2. Create a kubernetes Secret -> so it will provision the secret in azure
3. Inject the secret to a kubernetes Deployment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I have tried to check the same in my environment:***

***Code:*** Without key_vault_secrets_provider

**main.tf**:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
  name                = "kavyaexample-aks1"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  dns_prefix          = "kavyaexampleaks1"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
  }
}

output "client_certificate" {
  value     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.kube_config.0.client_certificate
  sensitive = true
}
```

[image]

- When checked the available [addons list  for my managed aks cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks/addon?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-addon-list)  through CLI , the “azure-keyvault-secrets-provider"  is shown as disabled .It means for the latest versions of terraform provider , they have providers .Just that it need to be enabled.

***Command:***

```
az aks addon list –name kavyaexample-aks1  --resource-group <myrg>
```

[image]

Now checked after adding key_vault_secrets_provider block with secret rotation enabled.
Main.tf:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
  name                = "kavyaexample-aks1"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  dns_prefix          = "cffggf"
  ....
key_vault_secrets_provider {
    secret_rotation_enabled = true
  }
  default_node_pool {
    name       = ”dfgdf”
      ...

}
```

**When checked for addon list using the same command:**

***`az aks addon list –name kavyaexample-aks1  --resource-group <myrg>`***

[image]

***The azure keyvault secret provider addon is being enabled***.

[image]

> which means adding  key_vault_secrets_provider block with secret
> rotation enabled itself means , we are making use of the azure
> keyvault secret provider addon.

Also check this [terraform-azurerm-aks issue on addon_profile being deprecated in latest terraform versions |github](https://github.com/Azure/terraform-azurerm-aks/pull/179)