# Azure AKS - How to install azure-keyvault-secrets-provider add-on using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file

I am in a stuck, Please check the azure rm version which I used.

How can I integrate Azure KeyVault with AKS? If I add under the addon profile, its throwing me error that this was not recognizable

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.75.0"
    }
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "=2.6.0"
    }


  }

}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

My AKS module,

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = local.aks_name
  location            = local.location
  resource_group_name = local.rg_name
  dns_prefix          = local.dns_prefix
  node_resource_group = "${local.rg_name}-AKS-BackEnd"
  kubernetes_version  = "1.26.0"

  default_node_pool {
    name            = "linux"
    node_count      = local.linux_node_count
    vm_size         = local.linux_vm_size
    os_disk_size_gb = local.linux_os_disk_size_gb
    type            = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    vnet_subnet_id  = local.subnet_id
    max_pods        = 250

    tags = merge(
      var.additional_aks_tags,
      var.additional_tags,
      {
        location    = var.location
      },
    )
  }

  linux_profile {
    admin_username = local.vm_user_name

    ssh_key {
      key_data = tls_private_key.ssh.public_key_openssh
    }
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin     = "azure"
    service_cidr       = "10.30.0.0/16"
    docker_bridge_cidr = "172.17.0.1/16"
    dns_service_ip     = "10.30.0.10"
    network_mode       = "transparent"
  }

  addon_profile {
    ingress_application_gateway {
      enabled      = true
      gateway_name = var.appgw_name
      subnet_id    = var.appgw_subnet_id
    }

    oms_agent {
      enabled                    = "true"
      log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.aks.id
    }
    http_application_routing {
      enabled = "false"
    }

  }
```

How to make addpn for Key_vault?

My Key_Vault module,

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vault" {
  name                        = local.kv_name
  location                    = local.location
  resource_group_name         = local.rg_name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = local.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false

  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = local.tenant_id
    object_id = local.aks_sp_object_id #Service Account created for AKS

    key_permissions = [
      "get", "list", "update", "create", "import", "delete", "recover", "backup", "restore",
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "get", "list", "delete", "recover", "backup", "restore", "set",
    ]

    certificate_permissions = [
      "get", "list", "update", "create", "import", "delete", "recover", "backup", "restore", "deleteissuers", "getissuers", "listissuers", "managecontacts", "manageissuers", "setissuers",
    ]
  }

  tags = merge(
    var.additional_kv_tags,
    var.additional_tags,
    {
      location = var.location
    },
  )

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      access_policy
    ]

  }
}
```

I already used before, as per suggestion,

```
  key_vault_secrets_provider {
    secret_rotation_enabled = true
  }
```

But its failed its saying the block is not valid argument

Request you to please help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: I dont think its part of the resource, so you'd need local-exec post sync action or something

Answer (score 0):

I have created Kubernetes cluster.

**Code:**

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
  name                = "kavexkcluster"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  dns_prefix          = "kavaexampleaks1"


  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
  }
}
```

[image]

Checked the  ***[addons list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks/addon?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-addon-list)*** for my managed aks cluster through CLI , where  the “azure-keyvault-secrets-provider" is shown as disabled .It means for the latest versions of terraform provider , the secrets providers need to be enabled.

Command:

**`az aks addon show -g myrg -n kavexkcluster   -a azure-keyvault-secrets-provider`**

**Response:**

Addon "azure-keyvault-secrets-provider" is not enabled in this cluster.

[image]

Check the following code by  adding **key_vault_secrets_provider** block with **secret rotation enabled.**

**Main.tf:**

Added **key_vault_secrets_provider**

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
  name                = "kavexkcluster"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  ...
  
  key_vault_secrets_provider {
    secret_rotation_enabled = true
  }


  default_node_pool {
    ...
  }

 ...
}
```

[image]

Checked for add-on using CLI

**`az aks addon show -g myrg -n kavexkcluster   -a azure-keyvault-secrets-provider`**

```
{
  "api_key": "azureKeyvaultSecretsProvider",
  "config": {
    "enableSecretRotation": "true",
    "rotationPollInterval": "2m"
  },
  "identity": {
    "clientId": "xx8",
    "objectId": "xxx6364c3",
    "resourceId": "/subscriptions/xx/resourcegroups/MC_xx_kavexkcluster_eastus/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/azurekeyvaultsecretsprovider-kavexkcluster"
  },
  "name": "azure-keyvault-secrets-provider"
}
```

[image]

**The azure keyvault secret provider addon is enabled.**

Comment: Hi, Yes I already tried the block as you suggested "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74809390/terraform-azure-aks-how-to-install-azure-keyvault-secrets-provider-add-on" But I got the issue like "the block is not valid"

Comment: Which version of terraform provider are you using?

Comment: I am using terraform version v1.2.7 and
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.75.0"
    }
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "=2.6.0"

Comment: I got an error like, │ Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on modules\aks\main.tf line 57, in resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks":
│   57:   key_vault_secrets_provider {
│
│ Blocks of type "key_vault_secrets_provider" are not expected here.

Comment: I am using the following version :    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.2"
    }   and sometimes 3.40. Can you check with these.